# how to fix memory leak on textview

Tags: android, memory-leaks, dagger-2, mvp

I am new in dagger and mvp pattern and i have a memory leak.
I'm not sure what is the cause of the memory leak.
I think the cause of the leak is txtCityName
but maybe my mistake is be in dagger or mvp.
If you need more detail to answer comment it please.

```java
@OnClick(R.id.constraintLayoutCity)
    void onCityClick() {
        searchPresenter.getCity();
    }

 public void getCity() {
        cities = new CharSequence[]{"manchester", "london", "madrid", "barcelona"};
        adb.setSingleChoiceItems(cities, 0,(d, n) -> {
            selectedCity = n;
            view.setCity(cities[n].toString());
            d.dismiss();
        });
        adb.setTitle("select a city");
        adb.show();
    }

 public void setCity(String city) {
        txtCityName.setText(city);
    }
```

````
LeakingInstance(referenceKey=7b6a8af5-1103-44d0-91c4-5cb25597d2a2, referenceName=, instanceClassName=androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout, watchDurationMillis=5151, excludedLeak=false, leakTrace=
┬
├─ ir.reservs.reservs.ui.main.search.SearchFragment
│    Leaking: NO (Fragment#mFragmentManager is not null)
│    ↓ SearchFragment.txtCityName
│                     ~~~~~~~~~~~
├─ androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
│    Leaking: YES (View#mAttachInfo is null)
│    View.mID=R.id.txtCityName (2131362166)
│    View.mWindowAttachCount=1
│    ↓ AppCompatTextView.mParent
├─ androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
│    Leaking: YES (View#mAttachInfo is null)
│    View.mID=R.id.constraintLayoutCity (2131361908)
│    View.mWindowAttachCount=1
│    ↓ ConstraintLayout.mParent
╰→ androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
​     Leaking: YES (RefWatcher was watching this)
, retainedHeapSize=null)```
````

i read that cause of textview memory leak is set textview out of screen.
but in my case my textview in right place. so i do't think leak is for that.

set on click listener on constraint layout has problem?

Comment: Could you post the code in the whole activity. How are using dagger here?

Comment: [link](https://github.com/rfmhb2/Reservs/blob/master/src/main/java/ir/reservs/reservs/ui/main/search/SearchFragment.java)
this is link of fragment that leak occurred.

Answer (score 0):

I am suspecting you are referencing txtCityName in your presenter. Usually, memory leak is caused by static members referencing an activity or fragment, then when that activity or fragment is destroyed by the system, the garbage collector is unable to clean it due to the static reference. Your presenter should never know anything about your fragment. Is txtCityName referenced in the presenter or anywhere in your project outside the fragment?

Comment: I think my problem was forget to unbinde ButterKinfe onDestroy. Because when i remove butterKnife lib my problem solved

Comment: Then you should have unbound your view in OnDestroy() rather than removing Butterknife at all unless you have other reasons to not want it in your project.

Comment: You mean `onDestroyView`